# Pandas: sum values two columns consisting of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe looking like this.

```
id       discount          current_price
01188    [0, 0, 0, 78]     [0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294]
```

The column `discount` and `price` are both consist of a list of integers. I would like to create a new column called `old_price` with the sum of `discount` and `price` element-wise.

So the new column would have:
`[0, 294, 294, 372, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294]`

Comment: So your discount and current_price lists are not the same length. Beside, do you have a single entry in your dataframe?

Comment: Yes, they are not always same lenght. No, there are +100.000 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a good old list-comprehension here with `itertools.zip_longest`.  This is probably the fastest you're going to get if you're set on using lists in a DataFrame.

---

```
from itertools import zip_longest

df.assign(old_price=[
    [x + y for x, y in zip_longest(d, c, fillvalue=0)]
    for d, c in zip(df.discount, df.current_price)
])
```

```
     id       discount                                     current_price                                         old_price
0  1188  [0, 0, 0, 78]  [0, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294]  [0, 294, 294, 372, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294, 294]
```

---

If all of your rows are the same length, you can probably optimize how your data is stored, but again, that's data dependent.